# Text-based Tensorflow unexpected result of train_function (empty logs)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create a NN model with Tensorflow using a few different text files. My code are as follows

```
DIRECTORY_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ake700/Python/main/Data_Science/Text_NeuralNetwork/text_files/"

FILE_NAMES = ['AK.txt', 'AZ.txt', 'SH.txt', 'DK.txt']

for name in FILE_NAMES:
  text_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(name, origin=DIRECTORY_URL+name)
  
parent_dir = pathlib.Path(text_dir).parent

list(parent_dir.iterdir())

def labeler(example, index):
  return example, tf.cast(index, tf.int64)

labeled_data_sets = []

for i, file_name in enumerate(FILE_NAMES):
  lines_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(os.path.join(parent_dir, file_name))
  labeled_dataset = lines_dataset.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex, i))
  labeled_data_sets.append(labeled_dataset)

BUFFER_SIZE = 50000
BATCH_SIZE = 64
VALIDATION_SIZE = 5000

all_labeled_data = labeled_data_sets[0]
for labeled_dataset in labeled_data_sets[1:]:
  all_labeled_data = all_labeled_data.concatenate(labeled_dataset)

all_labeled_data = all_labeled_data.shuffle(
    BUFFER_SIZE, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

for text, label in all_labeled_data.take(10):
  print("Sentence: ", text.numpy())
  print("Label:", label.numpy())

for ex in all_labeled_data.take(5):
  print(ex)
```

Output so far:

```
Sentence:  b'Molecules in milk absorb light to various degrees depending on the wavelength of light. Milk has a weak incident of visible light absorption mainly contributed by riboflavin in milk serum and ?carotene in milk fat . The ultraviolet absorption in milk is strongly affected by the aromatic rings of tyrosine and tryptophan and double bonds of the milk fat. In contrast strong water vapor absorption bands and other bands such as aliphatic ester bonds and CH of lipids peptide bonds of proteins OH groups of lactose and undissociated COOH groups contribute to the infrared light absorption in milk. '
Label: 2

(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Molecules in milk absorb light to various degrees depending on the wavelength of light. Milk has a weak incident of visible light absorption mainly contributed by riboflavin in milk serum and ?carotene in milk fat . The ultraviolet absorption in milk is strongly affected by the aromatic rings of tyrosine and tryptophan and double bonds of the milk fat.'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=2>)
```

Preparing dataset for training

```
tokenizer = tf_text.UnicodeScriptTokenizer()

def tokenize(text, unused_label):
  lower_case = tf_text.case_fold_utf8(text)
  return tokenizer.tokenize(lower_case)

tokenized_ds = all_labeled_data.map(tokenize)

for text_batch in tokenized_ds.take(5):
  print("Tokens: ", text_batch.numpy())

# Tokens:  [b'molecules' b'in' b'milk' b'absorb' b'light' b'to' b'various' b'degrees'
# b'depending' b'on' b'the' b'wavelength' b'of' b'light' b'.' b'milk'
# b'has' b'a' b'weak' b'incident' b'of' b'visible' b'light' b'absorption'

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

def configure_dataset(dataset):
  return dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

VOCAB_SIZE = 10000

tokenized_ds = configure_dataset(tokenized_ds)

vocab_dict = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for toks in tokenized_ds.as_numpy_iterator():
  for tok in toks:
    vocab_dict[tok] += 1

vocab = sorted(vocab_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
vocab = [token for token, count in vocab]
vocab = vocab[:VOCAB_SIZE]
vocab_size = len(vocab)
print("Vocab size: ", vocab_size)
print("First five vocab entries:", vocab[:5])

# Vocab size:  5678
# First five vocab entries: [b'the', b'.', b'of', b'and', b'in']

keys = vocab
values = range(2, len(vocab) + 2)  # Reserve `0` for padding, `1` for OOV tokens.

init = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
    keys, values, key_dtype=tf.string, value_dtype=tf.int64)

num_oov_buckets = 1
vocab_table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(init, num_oov_buckets)

def preprocess_text(text, label):
  standardized = tf_text.case_fold_utf8(text)
  tokenized = tokenizer.tokenize(standardized)
  vectorized = vocab_table.lookup(tokenized)
  return vectorized, label

example_text, example_label = next(iter(all_labeled_data))
print("Sentence: ", example_text.numpy())
vectorized_text, example_label = preprocess_text(example_text, example_label)
print("Vectorized sentence: ", vectorized_text.numpy())

# Sentence:  b'Molecules in milk absorb light to various degrees depending on the wavelength of light. Milk has a weak incident of visible light absorption mainly contributed by riboflavin in milk serum and ?carotene in milk fat ... '
#Vectorized sentence:  [1330    6    9 1478  174    7  182 1127 1028   23    2  853    4  174
#    3    9   67    8 1029  817    4 1128  174  193  695 1331   19 3575
#    6    9 1660    5  287 3576    6    9   99    3    2 1479  193    6
#    9   22  818  455   19    2 2697 2698    4 2699    5 2700    5  636
# 1661    4    2    9   99    3    6  390 1209   76 3577  193 1662    5
#   61 1662   74   17 3578 3579 1661    5 3580    4 1210 3581 1661    4
#  663 3582  484    4  913    5 3583 3584  484  561    7    2 2701  174
#  193    6    9    3]

all_encoded_data = all_labeled_data.map(preprocess_text)

train_data = all_encoded_data.skip(VALIDATION_SIZE).shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
validation_data = all_encoded_data.take(VALIDATION_SIZE)

train_data = train_data.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
validation_data = validation_data.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE)

sample_text, sample_labels = next(iter(validation_data))
print("Text batch shape: ", sample_text.shape)
print("Label batch shape: ", sample_labels.shape)
print("First text example: ", sample_text[0])
print("First label example: ", sample_labels[0])

# Text batch shape:  (64, 213)
# Label batch shape:  (64,)
# First text example:  tf.Tensor( [array] , shape=(213,), dtype=int64)
# First label example:  tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int64)

vocab_size += 2

train_data = configure_dataset(train_data)
validation_data = configure_dataset(validation_data)

def create_model(vocab_size, num_labels):
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 64, mask_zero=True),
      layers.Conv1D(64, 5, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=2),
      layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
      layers.Dense(num_labels)
  ])
  return model

model = create_model(vocab_size=vocab_size, num_labels=3)

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy'],
    run_eagerly=True)

history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=validation_data, epochs=3)
```

When compiling the model, I am getting this error

```
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

According to a previous post, it seems possible to fix this by using an [encoded array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71242821/valueerror-unexpected-result-of-train-function-empty-logs-for-rnn)? I'm not quite sure what this means and how it's applicable to my dataset/model. I also tried to append the `run_eagerly=True` in my `model.compile` statement to see more details, but it did not seem to do anything.

Any other models that might work with this type of text-based ML? I posted this in the [Tensorflow forum](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/text-based-tensorflow-unexpected-result-of-train-function-empty-logs/11075/5) as well for insight, but no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason you're using:

`tokenizer = tf_text.UnicodeScriptTokenizer()`

I've never used this but it might be causing some issues.

It looks like you're trying to do text classification.

Have you tried this guide?

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification

Comment: I used the example from one of [Tensorflow's page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text#run_inference_on_new_data_2) since it worked when I incorrectly imported my text files (non-raw GitHub files and had some HTML elements), so I had presumed it would work as well with the text files I'm using now especially as they seem to be similar to what the example used. It's not clear to me how the code wouldn't run the same as the example since the files, from my perspective, are similar. 

I will take a look at the link you provided to see if I can see why I'm getting an error.